# Problem in using the pysptools package in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I have appended path like this.
`sys.path.append('C:\Users\My Pc\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages')` 
where my pysptools package is installed.I am want t use its classification module.so i imported it like this.

```
import pysptools.classification as cl
```

When the plugin is loaded it gives error like below.When i am individually doing this in spyder it does not gives any error.but when i am calling it in qgis it gives error.
 Couldn't load plugin HyperspectralClassifier due to an error when calling its classFactory() method

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. ___________________________________________________________________________ Contents of C:\Users\My Pc\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\__check_build: setup.py                  setup.pyc                _check_build.pyd __init__.py              __init__.pyc ___________________________________________________________________________ It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly. If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or `make` in the source directory. If you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your Python version, your operating system and your platform. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 333, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/Users/My Pc/.qgis2/python/plugins\HyperspectralClassifier\__init__.py", line 34, in classFactory
    from .hyperspectral_classifier import HyperspectralClassifier
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/My Pc/.qgis2/python/plugins\HyperspectralClassifier\hyperspectral_classifier.py", line 34, in 
    import pysptools.classification as cl
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users\My Pc\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\pysptools\classification\__init__.py", line 5, in 
    from .km import KMeans
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users\My Pc\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\pysptools\classification\km.py", line 26, in 
    import sklearn.cluster as cluster
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users\My Pc\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 56, in 
    from . import __check_build
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users\My Pc\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\__check_build\__init__.py", line 46, in 
    raise_build_error(e)
  File "C:\Users\My Pc\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\__check_build\__init__.py", line 41, in raise_build_error
    %s""" % (e, local_dir, ''.join(dir_content).strip(), msg))
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
___________________________________________________________________________
Contents of C:\Users\My Pc\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\__check_build:
setup.py                  setup.pyc                 _check_build.pyd
__init__.py               __init__.pyc
___________________________________________________________________________
It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.

If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget
to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
`make` in the source directory.

If you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your
Python version, your operating system and your platform.


Python version: 2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] 
QGIS version: 2.18.4 Las Palmas, 59c1d21 

Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing
C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/My Pc/.qgis2/python
C:/Users/My Pc/.qgis2/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-win32.egg
C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\bin\python27.zip
C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib
C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\bin
C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27
c:\progra~2\qgis2~1.18\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg
c:\progra~2\qgis2~1.18\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win32.egg
c:\progra~2\qgis2~1.18\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg
c:\progra~2\qgis2~1.18\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2014.2-py2.7.egg
c:\progra~2\qgis2~1.18\apps\python27\lib\site-packages\shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win32.egg
C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL
C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
C:/Users/My Pc/.qgis2//python
C:\Users\My Pc\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages
C:\Users\My Pc\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages
C:\Users\My Pc\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages
```